Where to initialize my database connection in Next 13+?
NextJS newbie here, I need to setup a pretty simple connection to my MongoDB Atlas database using mongoose, but I can't find the proper place to put the initial connection so I can query the models from my server components later.
I don't think it would be correct to call the DB connection function before each time I query the database.
When i used expressJS I used to simply put the initial connection in my index file. What would be the equivalent here in Next 13+?

Take a look at official docs and demo from Vercel: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose
